# Connect to network says "Connection failed" but it actually isn't

Tags: macos, wifi, network, macbook-pro

On most occasions, when I try to connect to a new wi-fi network, after I enter the password and click "Connect" the connection dialog says "Connection failed" after a little pause, but *in fact* the connection is established, the menubar widget displays the network and everything works normally.

Except the network is never saved to the list of known networks, so every time I have to enter the password again.

What may be the issue here?

OS X 10.7.3, Macbook Air 13" late-2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I never got it fixed in Lion, no matter what I did some networks were still failing. However, upgrading to Mountain Lion did fix the issue without any effort on my side.

So my suggestion/"answer" is to upgrade to Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I could connect although it said "connection failed."  I observed that my network was also not in the preferred networks list. 
I resolved the problem in two steps. 
I manually entered my network's name and my networks password to keychain list. After that, in the system preferences advanced window, I manually added my network to the list of preferred networks by clicking on add button (+) and dragged it to the first line of the list. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this problem when your machine is coming out of sleep mode and/or after reboot you may want to try the following steps.

1. Apply all available system and software updates
2. Reset the WiFi Router
3. Add a New Network Location

   - Renew DHCP Lease

The following link has an in depth article that may be helpful in resolving your issues. It was written when 10.7.2 was new, but I have tried this and found success with 10.7.3.

[Still Having Lion Wi-Fi Problems?](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/06/lion-wi-fi-problems-solution-mac/)

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov Have you found out a solution for your wireless oddity?